# C# and Polly - How to Unwrap IAsyncPolicy to get to the ICircuitBreakerPolicy

Tags: c#, polly, circuit-breaker, policywrap, policy-registry

I am setting up Polly policies with some variant of:

```
Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync(failureThreshold, samplingDuration, minimumThroughput, durationOfBreak         )
    .WrapAsync(Policy.TimeoutAsync(timeout, TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic));
```

I am adding them to an `IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string>` and services dependent on Polly use the registry to get the policy.

Now I'm trying to add all circuit breaker statuses to the health check.  I am trying to do this by taking the PolicyRegistry and iterating through the policies.  However, the types in the registry are `IAsyncPolicy`, `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`, etc.

Using the debugger, I can see that the `Outer` property is an `AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy`, but that `Outer` property is not public so I can't use it and `policy as AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy` returns null.

Does anyone know how to 'unwrap' the `IAsyncPolicy` to get at the `AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy`?

Is there an out of the box solution for grabbing all circuit breakers registered with Polly?

Do I need to keep my own internal list of circuit breakers and add to it when creating the Polly policies?

*Note: I want to add a health check entry for each circuit breaker even if it is closed - just so I know things were registered correctly.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Polly almost every policy implements a bunch of interfaces:

- `AsyncPolicyWrap` implements `IAsyncPolicy`, `IsPolicy` and `IPolicyWrap`

  - We can use the last one to access the `Outer` / `Inner`
- `AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy` implements `IAsyncPolicy`, `IsPolicy` and `ICircuitBreakerPolicy`

  - We can use the last one to access the `CircuitState`

The `IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string>` is an [`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IsPolicy>>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/Registry/IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry.cs) so, you can iterate through it.

With a `foreach` the cb's state retrieval logic looks like this:

```
foreach (var (key, policy) in registry)
{
    if (policy is IPolicyWrap wrap)
    {
        if (wrap.Outer is ICircuitBreakerPolicy cb)
        {
            var state = cb.CircuitState;
        }
    }
}
```

The `IPolicyWrap` defines a function called `GetPolicy<T>` with which we can get rid of the inner `if` block

```
foreach (var (key, policy) in registry)
{
    if (policy is IPolicyWrap wrap)
    {
        var cb = wrap.GetPolicy<ICircuitBreakerPolicy>();
        var state = cb?.CircuitState;
    }
}
```

We can get rid of the other `if` block with some Linq

```
foreach (var policy in registry.Select(kp => kp.Value).Where(p => p is IPolicyWrap).Cast<IPolicyWrap>())
{
    var cb = policy.GetPolicy<ICircuitBreakerPolicy>();
    var state = cb?.CircuitState;  
}
```

---

The `GetPolicy<T>` or `GetPolicies<T>` have that advantage that it does not matter whether `T` is the `Outer` or the `Inner` or the `Inner`'s `Outer` ... it will find `T` or `T`s anywhere in the policy chain.

Comment: IPolicyWrap.Outer worked perfectly, thanks!